# Add Pushpin to MapControl in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'd like to add a Pushpin to a MapControl in a Windows 10 app, but it seems the control is gone since Windows 8.1.

[image: Pushpin]

It was as simple as that:

```
Pushpin locationPushpin = new Pushpin();                      
locationPushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
locationPushpin.Content = "You are here";
locationPushpin.Tag = "locationPushpin";
locationPushpin.Location = watcher.Position.Location;
this.map.Children.Add(locationPushpin);
this.map.SetView(watcher.Position.Location, 18.0);
```

But Pushpin type is not recognized anymore...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map control has changed little in UWP - take a look at [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.aspx).

As for adding Pushpins (POIs), you can [do it in couple of ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219696.aspx). For example:

```cs
// get position
Geopoint myPoint = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 51, Longitude = 0 });
//create POI
MapIcon myPOI = new MapIcon { Location = myPoint, NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0), Title = "My position", ZIndex = 0 };
// add to map and center it
myMap.MapElements.Add(myPOI);
myMap.Center = myPoint;
myMap.ZoomLevel = 10;
```

For more guidelines [visit MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219699.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to drag this MapIcon and get the location when user drops the MapIcon at some latitude and longitude?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar I haven't played with that much yet, but I would search in *MapControl* class and its events.

Comment: Will search the same.

Comment: Checked the Events of *MapControl* got one `CenterChanged - Occurs when the value of the Center property of the MapControl changes.` Will it be helpful?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar I think it may be - give it a try.